# When extending an ArrayAdapter and overriding getView, is passing the resource/textViewResourceId arguments completely redundant?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I've been messing around with custom ArrayAdapters for ListViews a bit, and when extending them I've always simply passed -1 (A non-existent resource id) as the resource argument to super. Are there any potential benefits (at all) to passing anything else in it's place when you also override getView?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any potential benefits (at all) to passing anything else in it's place when you also override getView?

Sure. If you pass your actual layout and `TextView` Resource ID, you can let the `super.getView()` method handle the `View` inflation and assigning the text on a single `TextView`. Then your `getView()` override would just need to "fill in the blanks".

For example, say we have the following simple list item class:

```
public class Item {
    String text;
    int imageResId;

    public Item(String text, int imageResId) {
        this.text = text;
        this.imageResId = imageResId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

And a simple item layout like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then our `ArrayAdapter` subclass could be simply this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, R.id.item_text, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_image))
            .setImageResource(getItem(position).imageResId);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Note that we implement a `toString()` override in our `Item` class to provide the correct `String` to `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: This was my first thought too, tried it out quickly but neglected to call super.getView . A very well put together example that can at least cut out a couple lines, thanks :)

Comment: No problem. I should mention that if you do pass an invalid layout resource in the constructor, you don't wanna call `super.getView()`, or you'll get a `Resources$NotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

```
super(context, R.layout.list_item_layout, R.id.item_text_inside_layout, items);
```

the 3rd parameter is usefull when you want to use custom layout for ListView/Gridview.

ArrayAdapter use `Object.toString()` to get the value of each item in Listview. It must have a TextView to display. So you have three options here

1. Use default layout for text item. like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`
2. Use custom layout for text item and provide textViewId to place your data.
   like `super(context, R.layout.list_item_layout, R.id.item_text_inside_layout, items);`
3. Use custom Adapter, not `ArrayAdapter`. You can extend `BaseAdapter` and inflate what view you want

Hope it help !

Comment: I was looking at the doc's and thought getView was declared only in ArrayAdapter, so was confused about exactly how Base or ListAdapter worked exactly, I saw your comment and so did a little more digging in the docs and saw it was actually declared in Adapter -doh!- thanks, I need to get a little bit more used to navigating the documentation it seems :)