# DrawerLayout OnClickListener Not Triggering

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

I am utilizing the Android DrawerLayout and have a Listview that contains my drawer items.

I am trying to implement an OnClickListener to no avail, the Toast is not triggering:

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    ArrayList<String> drawerTitleArray = new ArrayList<>();
    drawerTitleArray.add(0, "TEST");
    drawerTitleArray.add(1, "TEST 1");
    // Set the adapter for the list view
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item,
            drawerTitleArray));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            switch (adapterView.getId()){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CLICKED 0",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `switch (adapterView.getId())` - You want to switch on `i` - which is the position in the list - not `adapterView.getId()`. In fact, that parameter is usually named `position`.

Comment: Thanks Mike you can mark as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `switch` expression. `adapterView.getId()` will return the `View` ID for the `ListView`, not anything useful for determining the clicked item.

You want to switch on the item's position in the list, which is passed as the third parameter in `onItemClick()`. It's named `i` in your snippet, but it's usually named `position`, which is a little more informative.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to add icons to my list items?

Comment: You'll have to use a custom `Adapter`, or possibly a `SimpleAdapter`, but a `SimpleAdapter` is probably more work than the custom one. Lemme find a decent example.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37824459). It was for a different question altogether, but it demonstrates a simple `ArrayAdapter` subclass that adds an `ImageView` to the list items.